# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. when running a Python script using Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, click

I am new to AJAX and Flask and I am trying to make a Chrome extension that runs a Python script from Javascript. The script moves the mouse at a certain coordinate and clicks there.

This is the Javascript code:

```js
function click_coord() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/click_coord/",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
    }
    });
 }
```

This is the Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app) 
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route('/click_coord/', methods=['POST']) 
def click_coord():
    move_mouse()
    a = 15
    b = 17
    return jsonify(a+b)

def move_mouse():
    mouse = Controller()

    mouse.position = (201, 549)

    mouse.press(Button.left)
    mouse.release(Button.left)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The error I get is: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I only get this error if I call the function "move_mouse". If I don't, the code runs properly.

I saw in another post that a person had a problem because they didn't add the correct permissions  but i added: "permissions": ["tabs", "http://localhost/*"] to the Json manifest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a resource to your CORS(app, resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).